# Unable to point aws route 53 subdomain to digital ocean droplet ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-ocean, amazon-route53

I have a frontend hosted in a digital ocean droplet at 206.189.144.57

The problem is I can access website by IP but cannot route my subdomain to it.

<s>I used route 53 test records feature to simulate an A record pointing to the ip but it gives "Non-Existent Domain" error (but I'm able to access http://206.189.144.57, meaning the ip exist!)</s>

Here's a screenshot of the test record page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoLet.png)

---

(update) Here's my setup in route 53

| Record name | Type | Routing | Value/Route traffic to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| instapic-test.celiawongwsy.com | A | Simple | 206.189.144.57 |

and I have the ownership of celiawongwsy.com

**I am getting a DNS no error response at the route 53 test records feature. However, I am unable to access `instapic-test.celiawongwsy.com`, instead it only works if I directly access the ip `206.189.144.57`**

here's a screenshot[image: screenshot].

Comment: What record did you add in your hosted zone?

Comment: @SanilKhurana I have updated that in the question, thanks

Comment: you are not using AWS nameservers. So its obvious that Route53 will note resolve the A record. So point the domain to use the nameservers that are shown in the Route53 hosted zone and then Route53 will be able to resolve the domain to the IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using cloudFlare nameservers and are trying to manage DNS records using Route53 which is not correct.

If you want to manage the DNS by Route53, your domain's nameservers should be pointing to Route53's hosted zone records.

Answer (score 0):

Test records in Route53 don't work as you are expecting them to. Read this carefully:

> Test records to simulate the values that Route 53 returns in response
> to DNS queries. This tool displays the standard values that Route 53
> provides based on the settings in the hosted zone. The tool doesn’t
> send actual DNS queries.

Test records are used to test existing Route53 records. For A records you don't add the IP in the "Resolver IP Address" to make a test. The "Resolver IP Address" should normally be left unfilled, when testing a record.

You need to create the A record first, pointing mysubdomain.hostedzone.com to your IP. Then do a test by pasting mysubdomain into 'Record name' in 'Record to test'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have an A record setup in route 53 (pls see my question update) but I'm unable to access `instapic-test.celiawongwsy.com`, instead, a direct access to `206.189.144.57` still works, any idea about that?

Comment: you are using cloudflare nameservers.. so Route53 does not come into the picture anywhere..

Comment: Oh wow I forget about that cus that was setup long long time go! thankyou!

Comment: @Celia You probably accepted the wrong answer.